# iOS App Upload Warnings: checksum validation failed

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, application-loader

For first time I didn't get any error, but due to some reason the app got rejected.

But now I have tried twice, and getting this error, see image for reference.

[image]

Should I be worried about this, also I have tried uploading app using Application Loader and Xcode, it takes too much time and nothing happens even after 2 hours. My Interconnection is not bad. I can upload at 50-100 Kb/s.

Comment: Have you tried validating the app in organizer prior to submitting?

Comment: Yes, it is validated successfully, no issue. I had already uploaded another app a 6-8 months back with same account and same system, but this time I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: What version of Xcode?

Comment: Its the latest one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings can be ignored, as with all these warning, my app is approved and will be soon available for download.

I had tried uploading using both Application Loader and XCode. I had also tried changing the port as some post recommend to upload the exported IPA via Application Loader, but finally I was able to upload it via XCode.

I got the above message when uploaded via XCode.

Prior to uploading I had validated the app and it was successfully validated.

Once you got a message of `successful submission`, `wait for review` and ignore these warnings`.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your app? One time I remember I tried to upload an app which was more than 512Mb, and it took more than 1.5 hours, also it failed a couple of times.

Comment: 4.9 Mb estimated size in organizer and when exported its 4.3 Mb